# redux-observable how to keep passing the payload

Tags: redux, redux-observable

How can I continue to pass the payload to the rest of my operators?

For example:

```
login = (action$: ActionsObservable) => {
    return action$.ofType(SessionActions.LOGIN_USER)
      .mergeMap(({payload}) => {
        return this.http.post(`${BASE_URL}/auth/login`, payload)
          .map(result => ({
            type: SessionActions.LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
            payload: result.json().meta
          }))
          .catch(error => Observable.of({
            type: SessionActions.LOGIN_USER_ERROR
          }));
        });
  }
```

How can I pass the **payload** and the **result** to the map operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value for `payload` is available inside the `.map` because the function is defined with `payload` [in scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). You can use `payload` within that function with the way it is currently written:

```
.map(result => ({
  type: SessionActions.LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
  payload: {
    one: result.json().meta,
    two: payload /* this is in parent scope from mergeMap */
  }
}))
```

However, if you want to make it more explicit, one way is to use [`zip`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-zip) to combine observables:

```
login = (action$: ActionsObservable) => {
    return action$.ofType(SessionActions.LOGIN_USER)
      .mergeMap(({payload}) => {
        return Rx.Observable.zip(
            Rx.Observable.of(payload),
            this.http.post(`${BASE_URL}/auth/login`, payload),
            (payload, result) => { payload, result }
          )
          .map({ payload, result} => ({
            type: SessionActions.LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
            payload: result.json().meta
          }))
          .catch(error => Observable.of({
            type: SessionActions.LOGIN_USER_ERROR
          }));
        });
  }
```

Zip lets you combine several observables and provide a selector function to form the resulting object. Depending on your intentions, [combineLatest](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest) may suit your needs for similar problems, when you want the latest value of each source whenever any source emits.

Comment: Exactly. But just to reiterate again what Kyle said, you don't *need* to zip them, it's already in scope! Just reference it
    .map(result => ({
      type: SessionActions.LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
      payload: {
        one: result.json().meta,
        two: payload /* this is in parent scope from mergeMap */
      }
    }))